# Can I use an Android OS card on the new Nook Tablet?

Tags: nook-color

I am debating between purchasing the Kindle Fire or the Nook Tablet for my son.  My main concern with the Kindle is the limited memory.  I love the fact that the Nook has the slot for an SD card.  However, I've noticed that the prices on many of the games and such on the B&N Nook store are much more than those on Kindle.  I read somewhere that there is an Android OS card that can go into the Nook MicroSD slot to make it a full Android tablet.  Is this true?  Where would I get this card and how much is it?  (I'm really totally new to this... sorry).  Would this mean that I would be able to go to any Android App store and download games and such from there?  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An "Android OS" card? I've never heard of such a thing. If you've seen something like that it's probably a scam. That said, Nooks have been rooted and the Android Market installed.

Comment: @AlEverett It's not a scam.  The Nook Color boots off of the SD card before it boots off of the internal memory.  An "Android OS" card is a SD card that has CyanogenMod or similar loaded on it.  So when you plug in the SD card it boots into CyanogenMod and when it is removed it boots to the regular B&N software/OS (which is built on top of Android). Although you don't need to buy one of these, you can actually make the SD card yourself

Comment: @BryanDenny: Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

With the Nook Color it is possible to both root the tablet and install a custom ROM.  Some users have even gone so far as to setup their Nook Color to dual boot.  In this scenario, the unit will boot the stock Nook OS when allowed to boot from internal memory, or boot a custom ROM when instructed to boot from the SD card.  This is likely the scenario you read about with regard to an "Android OS card".

The Nook Tablet is quite similar to the Nook Color, but has been modified from the earlier device to have a locked bootloader that will only load a ROM signed by Barnes & Noble.  While it is still possible to gain root permission on this device, it is not (yet) possible to load a customer ROM.  Due to this, you may not boot the unit to an alternative ROM stored on the SD card.  You can, however, install the Amazon AppStore, Google Market, GMail, and other apps to get more utility from this tablet.  You can find instructions and details over at XDA-Developers:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1354487

Comment: Was just about to post this but you beat me to it. People sell these SD cards with CyanogenMod or some other ROM on them so you can boot from either the SD card or internal memory (I've done it with my Nook Color before).